# Bayes' rule and combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

Given the following information:

> - We have $2$ baskets with red and blue marbles in each basket.
> - In basket 1 there are $3$ red and $4$ blue.
> - In basket 2 there are $6$ red and $8$ blue.

and the following question:

> You draw $3$ marbles. If you know that you are definitely drawing from basket 1, what is the probability that the $3$ marbles are red.

I thought I could solve it using Bayes' rule, namely:

\begin{align*}
&P(\text{Red}\mid\text{Basket 1}) \\
&= \frac{P(\text{Basket 1}\mid\text{Red}) \cdot P(\text{Red})}{P(\text{Basket 1}\mid\text{Red}) \cdot P(\text{Red}) + P(\text{Basket 1}\mid\text{Blue}) \cdot P(\text{Blue})} \\
& = \frac{3}{7}
\end{align*}

However, via combinatorics we obtain a probability of $\frac{1}{35}$. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure why you wish to use Bayes' Theorem here.  However, it looks like you selected one marble from the basket rather than three marbles from the basket.  If you do insist on using Bayes' Theorem, you would have to account for all the ways you could select three marbles from the basket in the denominator, which is $\binom{7}{3}$.  In the numerator, you are told that you are selecting from basket 1, so you just have to count the number of ways of selecting three red marbles, which is $\binom{3}{3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use Bayes' formula. The first red ball has probability 3/7. Subtract one from the numerator and denominator for each subsequent draw.
P = (3/7)(2/6)(1/5) = 1/35

Comment: Thank you. I know that there is no need for it, but I still don't understand why it is incorrect in this case. How could I write it correctly using Bayes' formula?

Comment: Then you can do it three times, each time with new values for P(Red | Basket 1) and P(Red).

Comment: I mean P(Basket 1 | Red) and P(Red).